# Can't access CSS files in CodeIgniter assets folder, shows 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

My application folder structure is like

[image: root>assets>css+fonts+frontend+images+js]

but I can't access the contents in the `assets` folder. They always show "404 page not found".

As an example, `mysite.com/assets/frontend/page.css` shows the error. At the same time, `mysite.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` shows the error.

My `.htaccess` file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did you set your base url and autoload the url helper?

Comment: Yes i added base url and autoload the url helper. The code works fine in my development server(Easy PHP Dev Server) but not in my web hosting.

Comment: because you're most likely using relative links. When you are using mod_rewrite you will need to either use absolute links, a forward slash in front or the base tag in the head section.

Answer (score 2):

Add this rule to your htaccess rewrite:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
```

The issue is that when you remove index.php from your project, what you are actually doing is rewriting anything at that level to point to index.php...

If index.php wasn't being blocked you would see e.g. `http://localhost/index.php/assets/` etc...

You need to adjust the rewrite to ignore your assets folder with !^ (ignore starting with) then assets, so you can access that folder

You can check it working / not working by going to `mysite.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` in your browser and it saying it doesn't exist (with your current .htaccess file)

The rewrite you have `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` is doing this...

`^` is the start of string (uri)
`(` is the start of regex group
`.*` is the everything at first URI level
`)` is the end of regex group
`$` is the end of string

You are then telling it to effectively look past index.php/
then continue looking at $1

The rule I have given you is adding exceptions to what you already have to ignore certain URI segments